# Evaluate expressions until one returns true

Tags: c++, idioms

I have a `savePotentiometerState(...)` -function, which returns `true` if the there were changes to save, and `false` if nothing was done. Further, I know that on any single pass through my main loop, at most one of the potentiometers may have changed (due to the way they're read out).

This is on a very time-constrained embedded platform, so it's important (or at least matters) that I don't call `savePotentiometerState` more often than I have to. However, the code I come up with naturally seems silly, something likely to end up at thedailywtf:

```
if (!savePotentiometerState(pot1))
  if (!savePotentiometerState(pot2))
    ...
      if (!savePotentiometerState(potn));
```

Another way to do this would be to use short-circuit evaluation:

```
const bool retval = savePotentiometerState(pot1) || savePotentiometerState(pot2) || ... || savePotentiometerState(potn);
```

I suppose I could even drop the assignment here. But this doesn't feel like good style either, since I'm abusing the short circuiting of the `||` operator.

The various `potn` objects are member variables of the containing class, so there's no obvious way to write this as a loop.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, so my question is: is there an idiomatic/easy to read way to do this, which doesn't sacrifice efficiency? If it matters, I'm using C++17.

Comment: why do you think this would be an "absue" of the short circuiting operator? Thats exactly what it is good for...

Comment: Instead of having `N` different and distinct variables, why not have an array or a vector of `N` elements? Then it's easy to loop from start to end and break out of the loop once the function returns true. It would incidentally also make it much easier to add or remove objects as existing code doesn't need to be changed to reflect the new or removed variables. And of course make your classes less crowded with members.

Comment: @user463035818 I guess because I'm somehow thinking of `||` as a _logical_ operation, which I'm instead using here directly to control program flow... but you might be right, maybe this is the best way to do this.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your question is sprinkled with strange premises which makes it hard to understand what your real problem is

Comment: Everybody is trying vectorize and you guys want to go back to loop?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Since the potentiometers themselves are used in different ways at different places, so I prefer to give them explicit names. Of course, I could put them in an array and then use named references to them, but that again feels like  adding unnecessary boilerplate.

Comment: Well you could use named constants (macros or `const` or `constexpr` or even `enum`) for indexes into the array. Like `POT_FOR_THING1` or `POT_FOR_THING2` when you need to get a specific object from the array. Might add some extra boilerplate code in some places, but might also make other parts of the code *much* easier. Unless the condition you show won't include *all* of the elements in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can use C++17 you can leverage [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) and write a helper function to do the evaluation for you.

```
template<typename... Args>
bool returtnPotentiometerState(Args&&... args)
{
    return (... || savePotentiometerState(args));
}
```

and then you would call it like

```
if (returtnPotentiometerState(pot1, pot2, ..., potn))
```

This means you don't have a loop, and you get short circuiting.

Comment: I think this is it: it should be no slower than writing the conditions by hand, and I can name the helper function to signal exactly what is the _intention_ of the code.

Comment: @Timo This very well could be slower.  Since it takes be reference it has to dereference it to get it's value since the compiler can't know if something else made a modification.  Your `const bool retval = ` or the if statements are probably the fastest.  Jarods might also have the same speed since the references are local to the scope so the compiler knows they aren't changed.  You can use [quick bench](http://quick-bench.com/) to test.

Comment: Hmm, I'd imagine that since the references are local, and assuming that the helper gets inlined, it should be quite easy for the compiler to eliminate the references... but of course, assumption is the mother of all ******s, so maybe I will write the quick bench test tomorrow (thanks for the link, by the way!).

Comment: @Timo No problem.  If it's inlined then it shouldn't be an issue.  I just wanted to point out it could be slower.

Comment: I really like this post and I have already tested these solutions on a simple case yesterday, [DEMO](http://quick-bench.com/IfymV9b0disWqIQbcpXfc5aPqAQ).
As NathanOliver suggested, Jarod’s loop approach seems to show best performance.
Of course, template functions should be inlined and rather memory friendly.

Comment: @Hiroki thanks for writing the test! Indeed, the loop seems even faster than the naive `||`ing, funny enough! On the other hand, changing the compiler to GCC7.2 makes the naive way fastest, with the fold expression a very close second. In my case, the compiler is actually gcc-arm-none-eabi 7.2, so I'll need to try the benchmark using that, since the results are so close.

Answer (score 4):

Loop seems the way to go:

```
for (auto& pot : {std::ref(pot1), std::ref(pot2), /*..,*/ std::ref(potn)}) {
     if (savePotentiometerState(pot)) {
         break;
     }
}
```

Comment: +1, this is exactly the type of alternative I was looking for! I'll need to check how does this loop compile, though: if the compiler actually creates the array of references (as pointers) on the stack, this might be slower than just calling `savePotentiometerState` for all pots every time, and it would also take stack space (the system has a total of 96K RAM, so rather small amounts of memory matter here).

Answer (score 1):

Personally - I'd avoid the algorithm you're using.

I'd save the state for every pot all the time; and track the current and previous values; and then only call a given callback if if the value had changed.

This way, `savePotState` is always as fast as it needs to be for a given pot; and you'll never get into the state where pot1 to pot(n-1) can block potn from being read.

Comment: Excellent ... Readable, and simple to test.  Starvation (caused by improper use of hardware) can be very difficult to diagnose, or even recognize.  (Been there, Done that)